# Does MIPI CSI cameras should always preferred than USB UVC cameras?

Tags: camera, video

I'm attempting to DIY a car blind spot monitor system using camera + RPi board + display. For the camera part, there are cameras connected through MIPI CSI or USB UVC. I am a software developer only have very few hardware experiences, so I have several questions about them.

1. Does CSI always have better latency than UVC? The compressed MPEG and H.264 streams may have extra latency,  but does the "raw" streams from UVC still have higher latency than CSI?
2. I noticed CSI camera modules only have flat and short wires. Does CSI designed as a "device-internal" port so that I should never elongate the wire as long as one or two meters, and never expose the wire to outside environment?
3. Is MIPI CSI universally plug-and-play like UVC, or it need works to write drivers or device trees for each specific camera module?

Comment: `car blind monitor` ... do you mean `car blind spot monitor`? ... please update your post

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for your mention. I'm not native speaker so I'm not sure about its precise name in English. I then goggled the words and it seems "blind spot monitor" is correct.